# Xna clear the draw

Tags: c#, xna

I've got a code where my `spriteBatch` is drawing a text, my question is how to delete the text. `GraphicsDevice.Clear()` just change the color of the background.
My code is:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
      GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

      spriteBatch.Begin();

      Spiel.LoadGame();

      GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black); 

      Spiel.Intro();

      spriteBatch.End();

      base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);` indeed clears your background and fills it with the selected color. Everyting befor it gets erased. `Clear` should only be called at the beggining of the draw method. If you don't do this,

- you get the old solitair effect like when you completed a game.
- Some things are not draw.
- is a useless call.

You should use a boolean:

```
if (needToDrawText)
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Txt", new Vector2(100,100), Color.Black);
}
```

Comment: This answer should solve OP question. But still, I believe the problem comes from a misunderstanding of videogame logic... The draw method is called several times. Each draw clears the screen already (as you mentioned). This problem seems to be a game state issue (or lack of game states!).

Comment: This looks strangely similar to my answer.

Comment: @The Pc Luddite but I explained why it was wrong, not just what

Answer (score -1):

You just need to stop drawing it after `spriteBatch.Clear()`. The `Draw()` method is called whenever the game determines that it's time to draw (many times per second). Read its documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.draw.aspx).

For example, you could declare a field `bool needToDrawText`, and use it in your draw method like this:

```
if (needToDrawText)
{
     spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "This is a string", location, Color.Black);
}
```

This is a really general example. Obviously you should adjust it accordingly.